# Torque and diameter calculation

Tags: c++

There is a program I'm building in which I need to calculate torque and diameter. I have both equations in syntax but my output keeps being zero. What am I missing / doing wrong? (Disclaimer: I'm very new to this so please, I welcome constructive criticism! Anything to help me get better. Thanks).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double p, n, s, t, d; 
int main()
{

     cout << "Enter values for horsepower (p), rpm (n) and shear strength(s): ";
     cin >> p, n, s;

         t = 6300 * p / n;
         d = pow((16 * t) / s, 0.333);

     cout << setw(10) << "HP " << p << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "rpm " << n << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "psi " << s << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "torque " << t << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "diameter " << d << endl;



return 0;
}

//Output:
/*Enter values for horsepower (p), rpm (n) and shear strength (s): 20 1500 5000
   HP 20
  rpm 0
  psi 0
  torque inf
  diameter inf */
```

Comment: what all inputs you have tried out?

Comment: You have to compute your results **before** you output them. Move `t = ` and `d =` above all the `cout`s...

Comment: How about printing out the results *after* you calculate them?

Comment: warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
      cin >> p, n, s;

Comment: I've only attempted to input the p, n, and s per prof. instruction. The only result returning accurately is the p (HP).

Comment: Here is the output after running AND after moving the t = and d = to the top:

Enter values for horsepower (p), rpm (n) and shear strength (s): 20 1500 5000
       HP 20
      rpm 0
      psi 0
   torque inf
 diameter inf
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of the lines

```
 cout << "Enter values for horsepower (p), rpm (n) and shear strength(s): ";
 cin >> p, n, s;
```

is not correctly represented in code.

The second line does not read anything into `n` or `s`. It's an expression that uses the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). In this particular case, it evaluates `n` and `s` and discards the values.

It's as if you have:

```
 cin >> p;
 n;
 s;
```

Change that line to:

```
 cin >> p >> n >> s;
```

You can also be verbose and use:

```
 cin >> p;
 cin >> n;
 cin >> s;
```

Comment: Oh okay I see. I didn't realize I had to input them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Take your input like this (cin >> p >> n >> s) way and also print your result after result calculation you are are printing before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double p, n, s, t, d;
int main()
{

     cout << "Enter values for horsepower (p), rpm (n) and shear strength(s): ";
 //    cin >> p, n, s;
        cin >> p >> n >> s;
     cout << setw(10) << "HP " << p << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "rpm " << n << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "psi " << s << endl;

     t = 6300 * p / n;
     d = pow((16 * t) / s, 0.333);

     cout << setw(10) << "torque " << t << endl;
     cout << setw(10) << "diameter " << d << endl;


return 0;
}
```